# Is live refresh stopped?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, live-refresh

I am using the following URL for meta:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active

It gives me latest active post. But for last 1-2 hours, it does not shows me the post when it get activated. I have to press <kbd>F5</kbd> to get latest activated post. Is live refresh stopped?

Note: Save issue occurs in Stack Overflow. I am using the following link to get latest post.
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*+or+vb6?sort=newest&pagesize=50`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*+or+vb6?sort=newest&pagesize=50)

But here also I have to click <kbd>F5</kbd> to get latest questions.

PS:
Proof: When I posted this question, I did not get any notification like `(1)` in *Recently Activate Questions* tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found the culprit - while adding another redis server to the network our primary socket server decided to go down.  It should be fixed shortly.