# Active tab stopped live updating on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, live-refresh

Related: [Is live refresh stopped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156327/is-live-refresh-stopped)

Place in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active

The active tab works fine on meta, but not on SO.

Is this just a temporary issue from an update or installation process?

Comment: It is working fine for me at the moment.

Comment: What browser are you using? Did you reload the page at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I am using the newest version of chrome. I reload and it comes back with a list of active questions. But I do not see the "1 new question with activity" link show up.

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome, go to console and see if you get any error related to web sockets.

Comment: @Habib - I checked that, but only saw the usual warning for a jquery `event.preventDefault` issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main "active" tab, without selecting tags, does *not* live refresh. It never supported that, the page is too busy for this to be sustainable.

See [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox):

> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

Comment: Okay, so it was just a misunderstanding on my part then. I assumed from meta updating in that fashion for the active tab that SO did as well. Thanks for the clarification.